# HTML to XHTML - skip some tags completely. (C# beginner)

Tags: c#, xml, xhtml

I have started learning C# recently. MSDN has an example where you make a RSS application by directly getting the XML file, so I tried something of my own, and like most of the times, I didn't got it right. *Put the sigh sound here*.

As the pages are HTML, I tried looking for HTML to XHTML converters, and I found this one (which is pretty interesting) called [HTML-Cleaner](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/html2xhtmlcleaner.aspx).

It replaces unwanted tags with a `<dd>` tag, but I wish to skip those tags, so I made a modification of my own:

```
public override bool Read()
{
  bool status = base.Read();
  if( status )
  {
    if( base.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element )
    {
      dowrite = false;
      // Got a node with prefix. This must be one of those "<o:p>"
      // or something else.  Skip this node entirely. We want prefix-
      // less nodes so that the resultant XML requires no namespace.
      foreach (string line in AllowedTags)
      {
        if (base.Name == line || 
           (base.Name == "html" && first == false))
        { 
            dowrite = true; 
            first = true; 
        }
      } 

      if( base.Name.IndexOf(':') > 0 )
        dowrite=false;

      if(!dowrite)
        base.Skip();
    }
  }
    return status;
}
```

The problem is it only prints one `<dd>` tag and nothing else. Even if allowed tags are present, it skips them.

Why is this happening? Any help will be greatly appreciated. If you have alternative approaches, please feel free to suggest them.

---

EDIT : anyway to achieve this???

Comment: Just so you know, there are easier ways of parsing XML -- have a look at Linq to xml (`XDocument` class et al), or using XPath expressions with the `SelectNodes()` method of `XmlDocument`/`XmlElement`. Also, you may want to look into the HtmlAgilityPack (its API is modelled closely after that of `XmlDocument` and uses XPaths for querying)

Comment: HtmlAgilitypack is a great thing, but if you are able to convert your html to xml retaining only the tag you wish, then i gues, using XPath would be more easier, or will it be same as directly using HTmlAgilityPack.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the `Read` method returns XML nodes, not tags, so the entire contents of any not matching node will be dropped.

If the input is a typical HTML file, at some point during the recursive `Read` method the 'head' element will be found. This is not in the AllowedTags list so it, and all its descendent nodes will be `Skip`ped.

The same applies to the `body` element. It and all its descendents will be skipped.

That leaves the `html` element, which matches in your code and so gets inserted into the XML DOM.

Since `html` is not in the AllowedTags list, during the `HTMLWriter` phase, the html tags will get converted to `dd` tags, which is what you describe as your output.

I actually don't go a bundle on the html2xhtmlcleaner code, but I think you need to adapt the writer code rather than the reader code to achieve what you are trying to do.

Comment: @TarunG - Assuming you are following the HTML-cleaner example code, it will be part of the internal implementation of the writeNode method, as per the line `writer.WriteNode( reader, true );`

Comment: I have trying to work it out since the past 2 days, but nothing, when i try to modify the write tag, I get an error " NO XML tag open"..  Can you provide me any help on how to accomplish this??

Comment: @TarunG - It's difficult to do so on the basis of the code you've posted. I suggest that you open a new question, posting the code that you have that produces the "No XML tag open" error, and asking for help on why you get that error.